# gulp copy task completion delay

Tags: npm, gulp

I have some simple problem.. where I'm expecting a task to be complete before gulp says I'm done..

Below is the snippet I'm executing

```
            gulp.task('copyFiles',  function(cb) {
            gulp.src(['./bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/**',
                './bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**'])
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'))
                .on('finish', function() {
                    console.log('finished copying fonts');
                });
                cb();
                });
```

What I'm expecting as output is

```
started copyFiles..
finished copying fonts ==> It actually completes the copy
finished copyFiles after .. ms
```

What I get is

```
Started copyFiles..
finished copyFiles after .. ms
finished copying fonts ==> this message appears after the task completed.
```

The core problem I'm trying to deal with is that I have some CSS bundling step being performed after the copy step is done. Though I use utilities like run-sequence or async.series().. it is not helping because the task is exiting before it has really completed.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Thanks!